# Add column with psycopg2 doesn't recognise type

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to add a column with psycopg2, but I run into an error that says it can't recognise the type. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
alter_query_for_attributes =
            """
            ALTER TABLE {schema}.{table}
            ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS {sat_attributes} {sat_value};
            """
final_query_attributes = sql.SQL(alter_query_for_attributes).format(
                                                            schema = sql.Identifier("testSchema"),
                                                            table = sql.Identifier("address"),
                                                            sat_attributes=sql.Identifier(sat[0]),
                                                            sat_value=sql.Identifier(sat[1])
                                                            )
ALTER TABLE "testSchema"."address"
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS "address_line_1" "varchar(250)";
```

This gives me the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: type "varchar(250)" does not exist
LINE 12: ...        ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS "address_line_1" "varchar(2...
                                                          ^
```

Comment: The error is because the final sql query has a data type in double quotes. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=29d8dac6eaf6eb364e4f13b32afb5c67

Answer (score 1):

`"varchar(250)"` is treated as the exact name of a datatype, and there is no type named `"varchar(250)"`.  If want to use double quotes, then the size modifier needs to go outside the quotes, `"varchar"(250)`.  Or better yet, just drop the quotes if you know they are not needed. Your 'sat' tuple should probably have 3 fields, name, type, and optional type modifier.